# CGPath stroke lineWidth is inconsistent with CAShapeLayer

Tags: objective-c, vector, svg, calayer

[image: Image with line width 0.5]
[image: Image with line width 1.0]

The image on the left has a lineWidth of 0.5. The image on the right has a lineWidth of 1.0. I would expect the left image lines to be consistently wide, like the right image.

I'm adding lines to a CGMutablePath, but when I add it to my shapelayer, the lineWidths are inconsistent as you can see in the image.

Here's my code

```
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.5;
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil; 
shapeLayer.miterLimit = 0;
shapeLayer.path = path;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: oddly, it looks consistent with line width 1.

Comment: Any luck in fixing the problem? I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem myself. Later I found out that the problem was this line of code:

```
shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapSquare;
```

it caused the width of the line became doubled in every directions, left, right, top and bottom.

If it was set as `lineWidth = 2`, its width will be +1 to its left and right. +1 to its top and bottom.

The way to fix this is to leave the `lineCap` be. Use the default value: `kCALineCapButt`.